# Is there an obvious and simple improvement to validate stdin than what I am doing?

Tags: python, string, input, while-loop

I want to know what is the best way - and hopefully the standard way - of taking input from a user. I feel like what I am doing is tedious/messy.

Is what I am doing below considered *acceptable*, or should I look to improve it, not for efficiency sake, but because it leads to errors, inefficient, etc.?

```
while True:
    title = input('Enter a title (50 char): ')

    if len(title) > 50:
        print('Title too long; no more than 50 characters allowed')
    elif:
         # as many elifs as needed, such as '< 10', etc.
    else:
         break
```

Comment: Honestly, this looks fine to me.

Comment: Perhaps ask on [codereview.se]. But check their posting criteria first.

Comment: All cool, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with your approach, but I know what you mean - all those dangling elif's are untidy/inelegant.
Another possibility is to define an appropriate regular expression which can encode your permitted input in a very general manner, and do a single match query.
For example:

```
import re
permitted_re=re.compile('([ a-zA-Z0-9]{10, 50})(.*)')

while 1:
  my_try=input('Enter your title: ')
  a=permitted_re.match(my_try)
  if a and a.group(0)==a.group(1):
    break
  else:
    print('Try again: ')
```

The regular expression is in two parts. The first matches any character in the ranges listed between the square braces, repeated {minimum, maximum} times. If more than 50 characters were entered, the expression would still pass, so the second part traps any characters beyond 50. If the expression matches, group(0) holds the full string, and group(1) the first 50 characters of the match, so if there are more that 50 characters entered the if test will fail. There are maybe more bombproof and elegant options, if you are a regular expressions wizard!

Comment: Code example added, according to request.

Comment: Thanks, Ian, I appreciate that. To be honest, I have been meaning to check out regex, so this might be a good time to start :) I'm glad to know I wasn't going crazy. I can accept that there isn't *too, too* much that can be done to be improved, but regex would be good to use for sure.

Comment: I find myself using re (be careful - there are two regular expression modules available; regex is the other) a lot - of course, that's a function of the problems I need to solve. The learning curve is slightly steep to begin but it's worth the effort. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, *regex* was just an abbreviation I was using, I didn't know there was a module named that - I'll look out for it. Thanks, Ian :)